# On/Off Circuit for my USB LED

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

Its my very first question here and I am very new to circuits.

I have an LED with USB connect port that turns On when connected to my PC. I want to make a circuit and turn it On/Off using some programming language like C#.

I am a C# developer and want to use my skills with electronic hardware.

I'll really appreciate your response and guidance on this. I am a beginner so need to understand from basic level that how I can achieve my goal.

Comment: Welcome to Electronic SE. First of all this free online [Embedded Systems - Shape](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-03x) might be of interest to you.  Also there are many ways to solve your problem. I would look for USB to RS232 converter. Read the output from a USB into a small micro controller like PIC can covert your command to LED ON/OFF

Comment: I expect the LED just draws current from the USB port and isn't controlled by the PC in any way.  You would need to build an entirely new light that includes a microcontroller that a program on the PC can tell to turn the LED on or off.  This is a typical first program for people who start using the Arduino boards.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EE.SE,

Ideally this question would include more research on your end. A question going "I have this, I want this, help me" is usually considered much too broad and as such closed, since it sounds like "I have this issue, design my solution for me" and our time is usually quite expensive. So that annoys us.

That said, your problem may be solvable purely in software, trying to get the PC to disable the USB port through calls to the over-current controller that can individually switch on and off ports when they use too much current. That would be a non-EE solution that may be dependent on the exact motherboard.

It is definitely solvable by adding a chip and a transistor between your USB lamp and PC.

Start with looking at an FTDI FT232 chip, it creates a USB COM Port and you can use its D2XX drivers to directly control the hand-shaking pins on that port. There is also another chip they make that creates an 8 bit parallel set of lines on a virtual COM Port that you can use to control 8 signals simultaneously.

All you need to do from there is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw08Cv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The rest, is down to the research that you'll have to do yourself in place of what you'd normally have to do beforehand.

Comment: thank you very much for reply. Actually i am very new as i mentioned so i even didn't have any idea from where i should start, what should i ask. I apologize for asking an annoying question.


This is what actually i am looking for. A custom design...! I'll try to find the above mentioned hardware in my local market and compile some circuit. But before that, i'll try to make a circuit in CircuitLab. 

Thank you again. At least i have found a way to start. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for https://stackoverflow.com/. You need to find out how to get the USB driver to turn off the power to the USB socket. A quick look on stackoverflow  gives different opinions. Some say that it's not possible, some say it depends on the motherboard. If you cannot do it in software then you may have to build a circuit as suggested by @Asmyldof.

Comment: Yes Steve. I am looking to design my own circuit. Disabling the port is a bad idea as i am planning to do something bigger with circuits to control all the lights of my home. :) @Asmyldof provided a great guidance and i'll be following the steps he has provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. Following are some suggested steps

- Obtain a USB to UART converter board or cable.
- Obtain a simple micro controller board like a [Tiva Launch Pad](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c123gxl), [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) or a PIC
- Write your command from PC to the USB COM port
- Access your command via the UART Serial Port from your micro Controller
- Decode your command and switch on and off the LED on the TIVA launch Pad

USB to Serial Cable

[image]

**References:**

- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-03x)
- [Arduino Serial Communication](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial)
- [Olimex LTD USB-SERIAL-CABLE-F](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/USB-SERIAL-CABLE-F/1188-1018-ND/3471379?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla3471379&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1)
- [USB to TTL Serial Cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12977)

Comment: Thanks Mahendra. I think that would be a little hard to find USB to UART and Tiva Launch Pad in my local market. I am looking to design my own circuit by using some electronic stuff so that i can understand what each part of the circuit is doing. Just a quick question, Can we use Aruino as an alternative of Tiva Launch Pad?

Comment: @ChillaxDesigns, Yes your can use arduino. I have add link to help you. Just replace Tiva Launch pad with your Arduino board. But you still need a USB to UART converter, BTW most converter cable had the FTDI converter embedded in the cable.